# Unexpected "else" and function not running

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events

This code does not seem to be running correctly:

```
var addEventListener = (function () {
    "use strict";
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        return function (element, event, handler) {
            element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
        };
    } else {
        return function (element, event, handler) {
            element.attachEvent('on' + event, handler);
        };
    }
})();

addEventListener(window, 'onload', calcFailback);
```

Chrome returns:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object onload has no method 'addEventListener'

Jslint returns:

> Unexpected else.

Any ideas?

Comment: please don't overwrite your question with edits that destroy the original context of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a global variable `addEventListener`, it will be added as a property of `window`. So `window.addEventListener` (`element` === `window`, with this call) is actually referring to your custom function, not the native one. Use different name:

```
var myAddEventListener = (function() {
    "use strict";
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        return function(element, event, handler) {
            element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
        };
    } else {
        return function(element, event, handler) {
            element.attachEvent('on' + event, handler);
        };
    }
})(); //<-- invoke it
```

Also use `"load"`:

```
myAddEventListener( window, "load", function(){})
```

Comment: thanks, added that, but I get another error: Uncaught TypeError: Object onload has no method 'addEventListener'

Comment: It now works partially. It runs but cannot be called twice for some reason. I still get the JSlint error: Unexpected 'else' after 'return'. Any idea why?

Comment: @SnippetSpace the same function cannot be added twice as an event listener to the same element with the same `useCapture`. I don't care for JSLint so I don't know why `else` would not be "best practice" according to crockford.

Comment: The else is just not needed. If the first "if" is true the functions stops. If not you continue and return the 2e "return". You can remove the entire else{} :)